# Cuidaos, amigos y amigas

Tags: discusión

Esta pregunta no es sobre el sitio, sino sobre algo que creo más importante aún: vosotros.

Imagino que muchos que estáis leyendo lo hacéis confinados en casa debido al coronavirus, pasando las horas como buenamente podéis: con hijos correteando por casa mientras el teletrabajo aprieta, con la angustia de un familiar que no se encuentra bien o está solo, con ganas de salir de casa y airearos...

A todos, muchos ánimos. Nos han tocado días complicados que esperemos que sean breves.

Un abrazo a todos (virtual, por precaución :D) y cuidaos.

Comment: Efectivamente, en eso andamos. Gracias camarada, abrazo virtual.

Comment: Me recordó un capítulo de los padrinos mágicos... Saludos. https://medium.com/@tallerdevicente/narrativa-internet-55f88be9da73

Comment: @ArtEze no entiendo la referencia

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Me refería a esto, me hizo acordar la palabra virtual. _Timmy que está en su computador que a la vez es un virus que viaja por Internet_

Comment: Quedaos en casa por favor, estaréis salvando vidas y desahogando los servicios sanitarios si respetáis el aislamiento.

Comment: "*con hijos correteando por casa*" qué más quisiera yo que tener a retacos animando este aburrimiento xD

Comment: animo a todos!!

Comment: Un saludo a tod@s, a quedarse en casa en la medida de lo posible. Aquí en Guatemala acabamos de comenzar con las medidas, espero que pronto salgamos de esta situación! PD: una buena oportunidad para revisar los planes de continuidad del negocio!

Answer (score 9):

Aqui estamos en pie de lucha:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 8):

> con hijos correteando por casa mientras el teletrabajo aprieta

En mi caso, aún no tengo hijos, pero si dos pequeños diablillos que hacen más que corretear:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que ante la situación del coronavirus, se están tirando de los pelos (literalmente),curioso lo que me pasa en mi primer día de teletrabajo:escucho una pelea entre ellos y salgo a ver como el negrito le muerde la cola al otro y al voltearse me encuentro lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos, que estén bien ustedes y su familia.

Comment: ¡Qué envidia de perretes! El negrito te mira como diciendo ¿de qué se me acusa? ¿acaso tiene usted pruebas?

Answer (score 4):

¡Fuerza hermanos! Si alguien le entra a unas partidas de Star Craft II en las noches eso de las 7-9pm GTM -7 Hora del pacífico o fines de semana, me agregan en battle .net, mi nick es fredyfx#1268. Actualmente estoy en liga dorada 3.